# How to test controller method? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

How to test this (with or without RSpec)?

```
def create
  @foo = Model1.find(params[:array_of_ids])
  @foo.each do |f|
    @boo = Model2.new
    @boo.attributes = f.attributes
    @boo.save! unless Model2.exists?(@boo.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Anyone? I really need this.

Comment: Take a stab at solving this yourself first. For some hints on writing good questions, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask